# Covering map of the annulus

Tags: complex-analysis, covering-spaces

How to find universal covering map of the annulus of inner radius  $\frac{1}{R}$ and outer radius $R>1$ from the right half plane $H$ where $H=\{z|Re(z)>0\}$?

Comment: Nothing fruitful yet.

Answer (score 2):

The exponential function is a covering map from the vertical strip $\{z\in\mathbb C|s_1<\text{Re}(z)<s_2\}$ to an annulus. So a bijective map from the half plane to a strip is enough to answer this question now. A suitable branch of the logarithm function can do this easily. In fact the primary branch of $\log(z)$ takes the right half plane to the horizontal strip $\{z\in\mathbb C|-\pi/2<\text{Im}(z)<\pi/2\}$ bijectively and holomorphically. This can be made into the desired vertical strip by composing it with some appropriate multiplication.